# Detach RealmObject from Realm / Convert managed RealmObject to unmanaged Object

Tags: android, realm

I want to "detach" a `RealmObject` from its `Realm`, meaning that I want to be able to return a `RealmObject` from a method and be able to use it after I `close` the `Realm` instance.

Something like this:

```
public Person getPersonWithId(final Context context, final String personId){
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
    Person person = realm.where.....;
    realm.close();
    return person;
}
```

Currently `getPersonWithId(mContext, personId).getName()` will return an error, as expected.

Having a managed object will also mean the object is immutable (cannot be modified) and so any method updating the object like `person.setName(String name)` will fail due to the object being a managed object.

I wish there would be a method like `Person person = person.detachFromRealm();`

Does anyone know a solution/workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Android realm now supports attaching and detaching realm object. So you can do like this:

```
RealmObject objectCopy = realm.copyFromRealm(RealmObject object);
```

Here are details from the documentation:

> Instances of Realm objects can be either managed or unmanaged.
>
> Managed objects are persisted in Realm, are always up to date and
>   thread confined. They are generally more lightweight than the
>   unmanaged version as they take up less space on the Java heap.
>
> Unmanaged objects are just like ordinary Java objects, they are not
>   persisted and they will not be updated automatically. They can be
>   moved freely across threads.
>
> It is possible to convert between the two states using
>   Realm.copyToRealm() and Realm.copyFromRealm()

Comment: so copyToRealm returns managed object and copyFromRealm returns unmanaged?

Answer (score 3):

There is a feature request for this [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/931). There is no real great solution for this, only workarounds.

A **workaround** is to manually copy the data from one object to another. My `RealmObjects` have tons of fields so manually copying the properties from one object to another one is a NO GO.

Instead of manually writing "copying code" I decided to use [**MapStruct**](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct). Here's a [sandbox](https://github.com/lucamtudor/Realm-Sandbox) project with **Realm** and **MapStruct**. It seems to work just fine, at least for simple models.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but additional detail for your question. Would you kindly edit your question to include this, and then remove this "answer?" Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a valid answer though, as he answers the question of `Does anyone know a solution/workaround for this problem?`. He presents a possible workaround and provides some context about the project having a feature request about this.

Comment: Can you please remove this as the accepted answer, the feature request has been implemented: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1849